# Git Push error 56

Tags: git, push

I am having trouble with one of my Git pushes.  It fails, and now I have a couple of local commits blocked behind this.  I know this question has been asked before.  Everyone seems to give the answer to upgrade the http.postbuffer, however this has not worked for me.  I am new to Git, but it seems like the Push goes okay and then something falls apart afterward?  Not sure how to read the diagnostic messages coming back.

My failed entries to alleviate were:

```
git config --global http.postbuffer 524288000
git config http.postbuffer 524288000
```

Here is what I am getting back on a Push.  There is a 36MB DLL going in, which is the only thing that looks unusual to me.

```
git.exe push -v --progress  "origin" Develop:Develop

Counting objects: 99, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (78/78), done.
Writing objects: 100% (89/89), 13.13 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 89 (delta 19), reused 30 (delta 2)
POST git-receive-pack (13770696 bytes)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
Pushing to https://********
Everything up-to-date


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (193316 ms @ 4/7/2014 9:51:02 AM)
```

Any other suggestions would be appreciated !

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to back out the blocked Commits by doing "git reset --hard HEAD^" twice, then I put the second one back in, which worked fine.  Then with the troublesome project I staged a commit for the source files, a second for all the DLLs except the 35MB one, and pushed both successfully.  The last commit I staged the single big DLL, and it failed on Push.  So at least I have the majority of that project in, and I can take more time to figure out how to get this fat DLL in.